# Run mysql function from a separate class

Tags: java, mysql

I have two "files". The main program and a separate class.

In the class I get some data from the database and output it. Now I want my main file to grab that and output in the form (in textbox). But I don't know how to take the variable or run the function/class from the main program.

Main:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



 NewClass ha = new NewClass();



    System.out.println(ha);
}
```

Class:

```
package kalorier;


 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;

/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

  /**
 *
 * @author anton.jeppsson
 */


 public class NewClass {



      public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = null;
    String server = "localhost:3306";
    String password = "root";
    String user = "root";
    String db = "cms";
    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + db + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password;
    System.out.println("Connecting with " + connectionString);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
    while (rs.next()) {
       String ha = rs.getString("user_name");

     System.out.println(ha);





    }

}



}
```

Comment: Define a method in `NewClass` with `String` as return type. Cut and paste code from `main()` method to the newly created method. Now, call this method from `jButton1ActionPerformed()` method.

Comment: Okej thank you for your reply. Can you help me with an short example? @DeepikaRajani

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

**Button actionPerformed**

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    NewClass ha = new NewClass();
    for (String user : ha.doDatabaseStuff())
    {
      System.out.println(user);
    }
  }
```

**NewClass**

```
public class NewClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Maybe do other stuff here, or is this method even necessary?
  }

  public List<String> doDatabaseStuff() {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = null;
    String server = "localhost:3306";
    String password = "root";
    String user = "root";
    String db = "cms";
    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + db + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password;
    System.out.println("Connecting with " + connectionString);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
      results.add(rs.getString("user_name"));
    }

    return results;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I get the error "type list does not take parameters"?@Stefan

Comment: Do you have the correct import (`java.util.List`) and not `java.awt.List` ?

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Anton Seeing that you do a `SELECT * FROM users`, a suggestion would be to create a `List<User>` instead of a `List<String>` and build your `User` instances in the while loop. You can then access all public stuff from a User instance, not only the user name.